# A recruiter sent me a CV and the individual has now applied directly. Can I hire him without involving the recruiter to avoid the fee?

Tags: recruitment, united-kingdom

We’ve recently been struggling to fill a specialised position so decided to enlist the help of a recruitment company. They work on the basis that they send across CVs and you only pay a fee if you hire them.

We have not signed any agreements or contracts with the recruiter but have had a meeting and also exchanged emails and phone calls. We gave them a specific list of requirements and the instruction not to send anyone across who doesn’t meet the full criteria list. The reason for this is that we have had plenty of applicants who don’t quite fulfill the requirements so it wouldn’t be viable to hire using the recruiter (i.e. we would have to pay 15% of salary to the recruiter for someone we could have hired without their help).

They have ignored this instruction and sent a CV across of someone who just misses the requirements - I have told the recruiter that we would not hire this individual through them as we have similar applicants via our own website. I have since heard nothing from them.

Nearly a week later, the individual from the recruiter’s CV has now applied personally to our own email address. I assume that the recruiter has shared our information and he has then gone and researched the company.

If we decided that he was the nearest fit for the requirements of the role, would it be wrong to cut out the recruiter?

Obvious concerns would be any kind of legal action being taken but as we haven’t signed any agreements and I don’t recall any T&Cs being forwarded, I assume we’d be okay?

Comment: VTC i don't think it would be wrong, but then again i think ethics are beyond the pale for programmers, who see things in very b&w terms. But VTC because this is a company policy thing, and so should be directed to someone in HR management.

Comment: `1.` You should probably find out whether your communication with the recruiter created an implied contract. A contract need not always be written to be legally valid. `2.` You engaged the recruiter, they sent you a candidate, the candidate also applied directly. If you decided to hire the candidate and cut out the recruiter you most certainly would destroy any goodwill you have with the recruiter, would ruin any opportunity of using this recruiter in the future, and could possibly harm your ability to use other recruiters in the future once word gets around about your actions.

Comment: Do you want to do business with this recruiter in future?

Comment: If I were the candidate, or any candidate who heard of this, it would be a red flag. I would expect you to shaft me on my pay rises if I knew that you were a penny pincher whose word appears to be meaningless.  But, maybe that might just be me

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well, sort of no. Programmers tend to be really rigid - like, black and white stuff. And ethics is much more fluid than that. It's interesting, I think it's because programming is by nature b&w, so developers tend to have a very b&w view of things, instead of more nuanced. And ethics is nuanced, not b&w. If you want b&w ethics then you can check out modernism. It's pretty ugly.

Comment: Do not assume the candidate knew that he was submitting his application to the same company as the recruiter.  It is not uncommon for a candidate to use a recruiter while searching for work on their own.  Recruiters often dont tell the candidates which company they are submitting them to.  It could merely be coincidence.  This has happened to me on several occasions.

Answer (score 12):

> would it be wrong to cut out the recruiter?

Yes, because (as much as I dislike recruiters) the recruiter spent time and money finding that person for you that you now want to hire over other candidates.

> Obvious concerns would be any kind of legal action

I am not a lawyer, so don't take my word for it, but you probably do have a contract. Even though you didn't sign anything, it would probably constitute a verbal contract.

Comment: Even if there is no contract and it is perfectly legal to cut the recruiter out, consider that that is likely to make the recruiter very unhappy and much less likely to work with you in the future.

Comment: +1. Damage to reputation would be significant _with that recruiter_. You have no agreement with them, but you have contracted with them. Given all the circumstances, particularly wrt your statement about a partially qualified applicant, I think you're in a strong position to negotiate their fees downwards. If (when) they shout and scream, point out that you told them upfront you wouldn't pay for partially skilled. 5% is better than 0%.

Comment: Not only will it make the recruiter unlikely to want to work with you in the future, but they'll probably be highly motivated to speak negatively about your company to prospects and other recruiters. Don't underestimate the impact that can have.

Answer (score 9):

A key question:  Did the candidate hear about your position from the recruiter?  If so, the recruiting company did what you pay them to do: find good candidates.  If the candidate found you independently, you could make a case for not paying the recruiter.

I (in the US) follow the rule that the first person (recruiter, employee referral, the candidate herself) to present the candidate gets the credit.  That's because it's scrupulously fair, and because the cost of a recruiter fee is *nothing* compared to the long term value of a good co-worker.

Fair is good: it's a small world. Reputation matters. If I think someone cheated me, I never forget it, and I tell people about it.